# Check if sales-status in one country per campaign has changed and assign it to all countries per campaign in the results

Tags: mysql, sql, case, window-functions

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=65da52245413f3db9e0b0c9d2c2526dd)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    country VARCHAR(255),
    sales_status VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(campaign, country, sales_status, quantity
)
VALUES 
("C001", "DE", "demand", "100"),
("C001", "US", "shipped", "300"),
("C001", "NL", "shipped", "700"),
("C001", "FR", "shipped", "400"),

("C002", "DE", "demand", "500"),
("C002", "US", "demand", "900"),
("C002", "FR", "shipped", "200"),

("C003", "US", "demand", "600"),
("C003", "NL", "demand", "250"),
("C003", "FR", "demand", "150"),
("C003", "PL", "demand", "550"),

("C004", "DE", "shipped", "825"),
("C004", "PL", "shipped", "462");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
campaign |  country  |   sales_status  |     quantity
---------|-----------|-----------------|------------------       
C001     |     DE    |     shipped     |       100
C001     |     FR    |     shipped     |       400
C001     |     NL    |     shipped     |       700
C001     |     US    |     shipped     |       300
         |           |
C002     |     DE    |     shipped     |       500
C002     |     FR    |     shipped     |       200
C002     |     US    |     shipped     |       900
         |           |                 |
C003     |     FR    |     demand      |       150
C003     |     NL    |     demand      |       250
C003     |     PL    |     demand      |       550
         |           |                 |
C004     |     DE    |     shipped     |       250
C004     |     PL    |     shipped     |       550
```

---

In the table above you can see different `campaigns` and their `sales_staus` per `country.` 
Now, in the result I want to achieve that if **one** `country` **per** `campaign` is in `sales_status` **shipped** every other country should also be switched to `sales_status` **shipped**.

For example in `C002` the country `FR` is in `sales_status` **shipped**. 
Therefore, all the other `countries` are changed from **demand** to **shipped** in the results.

I tried this query but could not make it work:

```
SELECT
campaign,
country,
(CASE WHEN MIN(sales_status) OVER (PARTITION BY country) = MAX(sales_status) OVER (PARTITION BY country)
THEN MIN(sales_status) ELSE MAX(sales_status) END) AS sales_status,
quantity
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

What do I need to change to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if one country per campaign is in sales_status shipped every other country should also be switched to sales_status shipped.

You can use window functions and a `case` expression:

```
select
    campaign,
    country,
    case when max(sales_status = 'shipped') over(partition by campaign) = 1
        then 'shipped'
        else sales_status
    end as sales_status,
    quantity
from operations
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e8096da78adb12c632bbfd89101f32c9